# View extending CommonNavigator

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I am having a view which extends CommonNavigator.

I am creating a custom project through a CustomProjectCreation wizard.

Only refresh as given below works, but it refreshes all the projects each time a new project is created which should be avoided,

```
CommonNavigator resNav;
try {
resNav = (CommonNavigator)activePage.findView("view id");
resNav.getCommonViewer().refresh();
//resNav.getCommonViewer().refresh(newProject); //doesn't work
} catch (PartInitException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

ContentProvider looks as below
if(parentElement instanceof IWorkspaceRoot){
List customProjects = getCustomProjects();
return customProjects.toArray(new CustomProject[customProjects.size()]);
}
```

On Debug, getCommonViewer().refresh() calls the getChildren() method in the content provider.
getCommonViewer().refresh(newProject) doesn't make a call to ContentProvider

expandtolevel and setExpandedState aren't working...

How to achieve refresh in particular to the newly created project?
How to expand the created project?

Regards,
Aravind

Comment: Do you have the org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources plugin as well? This provides the stuff to listen to the resource change events and make sure the ProjectExplorer is in sync with those. I don't remember off the top of my head how you would hook it to your own CommonNavigator, but I think there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the problem is in the common navigator? If you have created the artifacts inside of your new project by using non Eclipse resource access methods (that is normal Java file IO instead of IResource, IFile and related code), then the model just does not know about the new content. If this is the case, you would need [`yourProjectResource.refreshLocal()`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_When_should_I_use_refreshLocal%3F) first.

Comment: I am creating IProject which contains IFile. But in my content provider, the created project is wrapped on a model object (new CustomProject(IProject)) which is returned. Will this be the reason why common navigator isn't able to detect the new content?

Comment: Yes, this is the reason, the CNF will track resource changes, but since it does not know about your model objects, the resource change mechanism is not going to help you. You have to access the CommonViewer and do the refresh of the object yourself when your model object changes.